# Allow athena along with white-listed IP addresses to access data

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I am planning to set this S3 Bucket Policy for bucket called "athenadata162".
I want only 2 office IP addresses and athena users from current account to have access to this bucket.
I will like to know if this policy is correctly written to serve the purpose.
It is based on the blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-define-least-privileged-permissions-for-actions-called-by-aws-services/

I am not sure how to set this part correctly...

```
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/BizMetricsQuery"
  },
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testme1623/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.2.3.4/32",
                        "5.6.7.8/32"
                    ], "aws:CalledVia": "athena.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I do not use the second Condition statement of NotIpAddress then the IP addresses are white listed correctly, but Athena has no access to files.

Comment: Athena does not support restricting or allowing access to Amazon S3 resources based on the aws:SourceIp condition key. refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/s3-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query with Athena it is the Athena service that accesses S3, and S3/IAM will see its IP and not the client's. The best you can do is probably to limit access to the bucket with `aws:CalledVia`, as you do, and apply the IP restriction at the Athena level, e.g. `athena:StartQueryExecution` – it wouldn't be the same thing, of course.

You could also set the [IP restriction on the assume role policy](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-restrict-calls-ip-addresses/) and then restrict access to the bucket to only that role. Users would be required to assume the role before running queries, and can only assume the role from the specified IP numbers.